# Vue 3 CLI Chat app bootstrap text won't align to the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am making a Vue app which part of its function is providing a real-time chat room for users under the supports of firestore. I have npm install bootstrap and v-chat-scroll in my Vue app. I originally tried to put some messages on the left-hand side of the chat room, while some on the right using v-if="equal_name(message)" within the span element(this function is provided below). But it didn't work. So I directly assigned class=" text-left" to my element. But the element still didn't align to the left. I can't figure out why.

```
    <template>
    <div class="container chat">
        <h2 class="text-primary text-center">Real-time chat</h2>
        <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">{{name}} </h5>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="text-secondary nomessages" v-if="messages.length == 0">
                    [no messages yet!]
                </p>
                <div class="messages" v-chat-scroll="{always: false, smooth:true}">
                    <div v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
                            <span class="text-info text-left">[ {{message.name}} ] : {{message.message}}</span>
                            <span class="text-secondary time">{{message.timestamp}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action">
                <CreateMessage :name="name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

below are the script and style of this Vue

```
<script>
    import CreateMessage from "@/components/CreateMessage";
    import fb from "@/firebase/init.js";
    import moment from "moment";

    export default{
        name: "Chat",
        props: {
            name: String
        },
        components:{
            CreateMessage
        },
        methods:{
            equal_name(message){
                if(message.name==this.name){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        data(){
            return{
                messages: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            let ref = fb.collection("messages").orderBy("timestamp");
            ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                    change.type = "added";
                    if(change.type == "added" ){
                        let doc = change.doc;
                        this.messages.push({
                            id: doc.id,
                            name: doc.data().name,
                            message: doc.data().message,
                            timestamp: moment(doc.data().timestamp).format("MMM Do YY")
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
.chat h2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    
}
.chat h5{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.chat span{
    font-size: 1.2em;

}
.chat .time{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
.messages{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: unset;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using flex in bootstrap.

```
<div v-if="equal_name(message)">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <div class="text-info">
                  [ {{ message.name }} ] : {{ message.message }}
                </div>
```

If I need the content aligns to the left, I use flex-row with v-if. If I need the content aligns to the right, I use flex-row-reverse and v-else

```
<div v-else>
              <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <div class="text-info">
                  [ {{ message.name }} ] : {{ message.message }}
                </div>
```

although I still don't know why I can't just assign class=" text-left" or "text-right" to do the stuff above.